# Mittag-Leffler for non-compact Riemann surfaces

Tags: cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

Quote from Grauert & Remmert's Theory of Stein spaces: 'Behnke and Stein showed in 1948 that the Mittag-Leffier Partial Fraction Theorem and the Weierstrass
Product Theorem (i.e. the Cousin Theorems) are valid on non-compact Riemann
surfaces. The following lemma appears at the end of their paper:

Hilfssatz C: Let $D$ be a discrete set in a non-compact Riemann surface $X$. For
every $p\in D$ let $z_p$ be a local coordinate at p. Suppose that at all $p \in D$ there is
prescribed a finite Laurent-Taylor series $h_p = \sum_{\nu=-m_p}^{n_p}a_\nu z_p^{\nu}$, $0\leq m_p,n_p<\infty$. Then
there exists a function $H$ which is meromorphic on $X$, holomorphic on $X\setminus D$, and
whose Laurent development at $p$ with respect to $z_p$ agrees with $h_p$ up to the $n_p$-th term.'

Does $H$ still exist if we ask it to have no zeroes in $X\setminus D$? That is, I want to $H$ to realize *exactly* a prescribed divisor. References are welcomed.

Comment: I can't see any reason why not, maybe check _Coherent Analytic Sheaves_ by GR, or Forster's book on Riemann surfaces.

Answer (score 3):

Considering the reciprocal function, it is sufficient to construct a holomorphic function with prescribed zeros, and prescribed finite portions of Taylor series at those zeros. For the plane and the unit disk this is an interpolation problem whose positive solution follows from Weierstrass's theorem (and its generalization to the unit disk).

Comment: I do not understand how you get a function on your original Riemann surface from a function on its universal cover.